# How to open a exe in a new window w/ multiple command lines?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to run a file, where it automaticly enters multiple commands in that new window.

I have already tried "&" "&&" "|" and "||"

cmd /k "diskpart.exe & select disk 0 && echo Disk 0 has been selected."

Comment: Even if you manage to run this it won't work. You want diskpart to execute `select disk`. Use io redirection

Comment: Write your diskpart commands one per line inside a text file and use `DiskPart /S "yourfile.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Compo!
It is exactly the thing for what I am looking for!
Great Job!

> DiskPart /S "yourfile.txt"